# JPA (or other alternatives) for persisting in-memory queue

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, jms

I have an application which uses an im-memory implementation of Queue. I need to add persistence to this queue "with as less changes to my code". I want to use JPA here - I guess adding annotations would ease my work a bit. But am I right ? I have no experiene with JPA yet...any guidance will be good.

After going through some other posts, JMS is also an option I can consider. But wouldn't JMS result in a lot of code changes ?

[Project Voldemort](http://dunithd.wordpress.com/2010/07/16/implementing-a-persistent-fifo-queue-in-java-using-voldemort/) also seems a good option, which I am curretly going through.

Any other ideas are welcome. Thanks !

Comment: What kind of load?  Does your application already include/use a relational database?  It is atomically synchronized or eventually consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can persist a queue if it implements 'Collection'. Annotate wit @ElementCollection and see.